# Different color folder in usr/local/bin

Tags: homebrew, bin, iterm2

I'm using iterm2 and looking at what is in usr/local/bin. Some apps were installed with homebrew. Others i'm not sure how they got there. Most of the folders are purple. Some are red. So ex: meteor and wireshark are red. I cannot figure out the meaning of this.

Answer (score 1):

The default `ls` colorscheme on macOS shows executable files as red and [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) as purple.

Homebrew organize its installed packages under specific directories that look like `/usr/local/Cellar/<name>/<version>`. In order to make them discoverable by the rest of the system, it creates symbolic links from standard locations such as `/usr/local/bin` to those directories.

Hence, the symbolic links (in purple) you see in that directory were very likely installed by Homebrew; while executable files (in red) were installed by other means.

You can have a more detailed view by using `ls -l`. Among other things, it’ll tell you the target of each symbolic link. If you see something like `foo -> ../Cellar/bar/1.2.3/bin/foo`, that’s something installed by Homebrew.